# How to add status code to Rails public html files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

This might seem counter-intuitive, but I have a 404.html page in the `public` folder. Using `mypage.com/404.html` would directly hit this page and show that static HTML page with a `200`. Is there a way to continue to use that exact page/location and change the status to a `404`?

The other (non-ideal) solution would obviously be move that 404.html to a `views` folder and write an action within `ApplicationController` and `routes.rb` to do this redirection.

**TL;DR:** Return 404.html page in `public` with a `404` status code.

Comment: Adding a `get '404.html', to:r edirect('/404.html', status: 404)` still wouldn't work since Rails sees the 404.html in public and skips routing completely

Comment: I understand the question and intent; and there are certainly many ways to do that. But, why would you like to change the behavior? 404.html is just a page too.

Comment: @kiddorails to be able to use with status monitoring tools which look for 404, if something in the Rails stack is down - 404.html within `public` will be served for several error conditions, but a 200 looks like success to any external services.

Answer (score 1):

I will particularly advice to NOT do many code changes **inside** your application to achieve this.

Long way:

1. Remove `public/404.html`.
2. Add [middleware like this](https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/08/404-with-rails-4/) in stack which checks for status code and routes it via rails pipeline.

Simpler way:

Write a rule in your reverse proxy(nginx/apache/etc) to serve `404` status code when `/404.html` or `/404` is requested.

```
#nginx
location /404/ {
  return 404;
}

location /404.html/ {
  return 404;
}
```

Comment: The nginx conf change might be just what I want.